# Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading, httprequest

I'm trying MultiThreading and send 4 request in the same time to php file from android but im getting this problem 
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
how to solve it please

And Here's my Connection Code

```
   package system.registrationsystem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {



    JSONObject jobj=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    static String json="";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient=null;
    HttpPost httpPost=null;


public JSONParser(){    
}
public void OpenConnection(String url){
     httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpPost=new HttpPost(url);


}

public void InsertDataIntoServer(List<NameValuePair> parm){
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    HttpResponse response=null;
    HttpEntity entity=null;
    try{

        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parm));
         response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        entity=response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
    while( (line=reader.readLine()) !=null ){
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }


    is.close();
    response.getEntity().consumeContent();

    Log.v("Return SB",sb.toString());

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix the problem? What do you think the problem is and what has prevented you until now from fixing it yourself?

Comment: At which moment/statement do you get that message. The message comes from the server? Where did you receive it? It looks the server accepts only one connection at a time from one ip address.